# What does a high GINI in a random forest model imply?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, gini

I ran a classification problem using random forest to predict whether a customer will have more than zero revenue in the next 12 months. I am getting a gini of 95 and accuracy of 90% as well. I know what accuracy means from the coefficient matrix but I am wondering what a high gini implies and cannot find anything online? An explanation or link to one would be very useful

Comment: The Gini index is a measure of homogeneity in the dual partition created by each node of each tree in the forest.

Comment: So a high gini implies that the node splits are highly homogeneous? Sorry I am still trying to wrap my head around this concept